# I read about the Sieve of Eratosthenes yesterday and wanted to implement it

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm looking for some feedback on my implementation of the algorithm. How can I improve it? I ran into problems when calculating the larger prime numbers > 46349 due to integer overflow, but fixed that by using sqrt instead of pow.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    const int CAP = number;
    bool * prime = new bool[CAP];

    for(int i = 0; i <= CAP; i++){ //sets all to true for the marking
        prime[i] = true;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= number; i++){
        if(i <= sqrt(number) && prime[i] == true){
            for(int j = i*i; j <=number; j++){ //if %i == 0 mark false
                if(j % i == 0){               //haven't tried another way
                    prime[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= number; i++){
        if(prime[i] == true){
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing (working?) code.

Comment: stackoverflow is for code with bugs, but make sure to explain the problems that you got because people don't like just having the codedumped and having to guess.

Comment: Try over at codereview.SE, they are more partialto this sort of question.

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also note that there is a codereview.stackexchange.com which is for **working code** that you want to get reviewed and suggestions to improve for.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely be posting there often.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing an array out of bounds at:

```
bool * prime = new bool[CAP];

for(int i = 0; i <= CAP; i++)
```

you should change it to use `<` instead of `<=`

Note that the same applies for the `<=` in your other loops too.

Comment: I've made those changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few efficiency things you can do, in addition to fixing the array out of bounds bugs you will get in all of your loops (use i < length, not i <= length). For one, you can use memset on the array to set everything in it to true.

In addition, your inner for loop (with j as the variable) does extra stuff it doesn't need to; instead of checking if j % i == 0 for each j, just replace j++ with j  += i so j will always be divisible by i. A lesser optimization would be to change the bound on your outer loop ( i <= sqrt(number) so you don't need the if statement before the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do away with the `sqrt` completely.  You have:

```
if(i <= sqrt(number) && prime[i] == true) {
```

but the first condition is redundant with the next line, where `i*i` is compared to `number`.

```
   for(int j = i*i; j <= number; j++) {
```

So the first becomes just

```
if (prime[i]) {
```